Reading in csv or xlsx files / folders when using dynamic file path generation (I don't know if this is the right term)
Im running into an issue with my R script, where read.csv fails to read a csv from a file path. Essentially the goal of my script is to build a file path based on the step variable input. My issue is that it will create the correct file path. But R fails to open the connection. This is the part of the script where it builds the file path:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
# ==================== #
Step <- "pntSetting"
# Step Check
properParam <- c('Cleaning', 100, 150, 175, 200, 225, 'pntSetting', 'Final')
Param <- c('Cleaning', 'pntSetting', 'Final')
if(!tolower(Step) %in% tolower(properParam)) {                                  # If Step does not match anything in properParams regardless of capitalization
  stop(paste0('Step needs to be ', paste(properParam, collapse = ", ")))          # Stop script and print the appropriate options
} else if (!Step %in% properParam) {                                            # If Step does not match anything in properParams regarding capitalization
  Step <- Param[grep(tolower(Step), tolower(Param))]                              # use grep() to replace Step with the appropriate Step with correct capitalization
} else if (is.numeric(Step)) {                                                  # If Step is of numeric data type
    Step <- as.character(Step)                                                    # convert to character data type
}
# ==================== #
colKeep <- c("LongLat_ID", "LAT_GPS", "LONG_GPS", "perflac_all", "strSize", "lc01", "lc02", "lc03", "lc04", "lc05", "lc06", "lc07", "lc08", "lc09")
colRm <- c("LongLat_ID", "LAT_GPS", "LONG_GPS")

# Folder Paths
# Data Dictionaries
paramVers <- list(   'Cleaning' = 0, 
                          '100' = 1, 
                          '150' = 2, 
                          '175' = 3, 
                          '200' = 4, 
                          '225' = 5, 
                   'pntSetting' = 5.5, 
                        'Final' = 6 )
OutSuffix <- list('0'   = "_Cleaning", 
                  '1'   = "_100m", 
                  '2'   = "_150m", 
                  '3'   = "_175m", 
                  '4'   = "_200m", 
                  '5'   = "_225m", 
                  '5.5' = "_pntSeting", 
                  '6'   = "_Final" )
InSuffix <- list(  '0' = "_Cleaning", 
                   '1' = "_100m", 
                   '2' = "_150m", 
                   '3' = "_175m", 
                   '4' = "_200m", 
                   '5' = "_225m", 
                 '5.5' = "_255m", 
                   '6' = "_Final" )
Version <- paramVers[[Step]]
inputsuffix <- InSuffix[[as.character(Version)]]
outputsuffix <- OutSuffix[[as.character(Version)]]

if(Step == 'pntSetting'){                     
  iteration <- paste0("A", (Version - 0.5))   # Using "Version to create the file prefix
} else {
  iteration <- paste0("A", Version)           # Using "Version to create the file prefix
}

# Base file paths
base_path <- file.path("Data", "Analysis")                          # Data/Analysis
folder <- paste0(iteration, inputsuffix)
file_path <- file.path(base_path, folder)                           # Data/Analysis/A?_[inputSuffix]

file_path
dir.exists(file_path)
# file_path <- file.path(base_path, paste0(iteration, inputsuffix))   
repFile_path <- file.path(file_path, "Adjust")                      # Data/Analysis/A?_[inputSuffix]/Adjust
snapVal_path <- file.path(base_path, "FullDat")                     # Data/Analysis/FullDat

# File Paths
# File prior to pntSetting
input_file <- file.path(file_path, paste0(iteration, "_QISBLongLatNA.csv")) # csv with the most up to unsnapped station prior to adjustment
# Adjustment Files
ReplaceMissingCoords <- file.path(repFile_path, "ReplaceMissingCoords.csv") # csv for the unsnapped stations
ReAdjustWrongCoords <- file.path(repFile_path, "ReAdjustCoords.csv")        # csv with readjusted coordinates of already snapped stations
HydroMisMatch <- file.path(repFile_path, "HydroMismatch.csv")               # csv with hydrological mismatched stations. 

# QISB Files
snapVal <- file.path(snapVal_path, paste0(iteration, "_QISB.csv")) # The most recent QISB file
repFile_path
dir.exists(repFile_path)

ReplaceMissCoord <- read.csv(ReplaceMissingCoords)    # Manually Snapped Missing Sample Sites
ReAdjustCoords <- read.csv(ReAdjustWrongCoords)       # Sample Sites with Manually adjusted Coordinates.
pntsRemove <- read.csv(HydroMisMatch)                 # Confirmed Hydrological Mismatched

When I run this part of my script. receive this error:

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

What I've been testing is using "pntSetting" as my "step" parameter, which would give me values of 5.5, _255m, and _pntSetting, for "Version", "inputsuffix" and "outputsuffix" variables, respectively.
The overall file path looks like this: "Data/Analysis/A5_225m/Adjust"
By recreating different versions of the folder path, I've deduced the problem down to my "inputsuffix" variable ("_255m" in file path example). I have successfully been able to have the file read when I manually type in "_255m", but if I use the inputsuffix variable, it will throw the error. The Version variable does not seem to be a problem, as it works in all cases. I have also checked for any typos, and the folder path is correct. I've also tried absolute paths (including and excluding working directory path) to test, and the file reads.
Is anyone familiar with this issue, could it be because of my data dictionaries that I'm using to generate folder paths?
UPDATE / EDIT:
As suggested by @margusl, I tried
list.files(file_path, recursive = TRUE) |> dput()

which outputs:
character(0)

While
list.files(Data/Analysis, recursive = TRUE) |> dput()

will output:
c("A0_Cleaning/A0_QISBLongLat.csv", "A1_100m/A1_QISBLongLat.xlsx", 
"A1_100m/A1_QISBLongLatNA.csv", "A1_100m/A1_QISBLongLatVal.csv", 
"A2_150m/A2_QISBLongLat.xlsx", "A2_150m/A2_QISBLongLatNA.csv", 
"A2_150m/A2_QISBLongLatVal.csv", "A3_175m/A3_QISBLongLat.xlsx", 
"A3_175m/A3_QISBLongLatNA.csv", "A3_175m/A3_QISBLongLatNA.xlsx", 
"A3_175m/A3_QISBLongLatVal.csv", "A4_200m/A4_QISBLongLat.xlsx", 
"A4_200m/A4_QISBLongLatNA.csv", "A4_200m/A4_QISBLongLatVal.csv", 
"A5_225m/A5_QISBLongLat.xlsx", "A5_225m/A5_QISBLongLatNA.csv", 
"A5_225m/A5_QISBLongLatNAdjust.csv", "A5_225m/A5_QISBLongLatVal.csv", 
"A5_225m/Adjust/HydroMismatch.csv", "A5_225m/Adjust/HydroMismatch.xlsx", 
"A5_225m/Adjust/missingStreamOrder.csv", "A5_225m/Adjust/ReAdjustCoords.csv", 
"A5_225m/Adjust/ReAdjustCoords.xlsx", "A5_225m/Adjust/ReplaceMissingCoords.csv", 
"A5_225m/Adjust/ReplaceMissingCoords.xlsx", "A5_225m/Adjust/unsurePnts.csv", 
"A6_Final/A6_LongLat.csv", "A6_Final/A6_PercflacHarv.xls", "A6_Final/A6_QISBLongLat.xlsx", 
"A6_Final/A6_QISBLongLatNA.csv", "A6_Final/A6_QISBLongLatVal.csv", 
"FullDat/A0_QISB.csv", "FullDat/A1_QISB.csv", "FullDat/A2_QISB.csv", 
"FullDat/A3_QISB.csv", "FullDat/A4_QISB.csv", "FullDat/A5_QISB.csv", 
"FullDat/A6_QISB.csv")

The current problem that I've deduced is that there seems to be a problem with the concatenation of "A5_225m". The same path will work, if I copy and paste it, and run as a relative path.

Maybe tried already, try to print filenames before reading, and check manually if they all exist?

This looks like a rather fragile approach.  If  file names are not sensitive, perhaps you can share output from list.files(file_path, recursive = TRUE) |> dput() .

@margusl What does this code do? Does it "rewrite" or "reformat" the variable?

@zx8754 I have tried to print filenames before reading. They are identical, but they don't read. and Im not entirely sure why.

@FelixChan , it will return a list of files in your file_path in a reproducible form. If you include this output as-is to your question, it may help others to figure out why/how your actual file names differ from those generated by your script.  It may not cover some encoding issues and does not quite tick the "Minimal, Reproducible Example" chekbox ( https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example )  but it's still better than nothing.
